# Float variable to hex C++ arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-c++

I encountered an issue while having fun with Arduino. I am currently using the first version of Arduino IDE (v 1.18.49.0).

Problem is that I can't figure out how to **convert float value to hex**. I am trying to use various solutions that occurred earlier on StackOverflow, but none of them seemed to work for me. **My best attempt is:**

```
char data[9];
float a = 3.141592654;
sprintf(data, "%x", *(unsigned int*)&a);
Serial.println(data);
```

**Expected Result:** 40490fdb

**Actual Result:** fdb

What's surprising using **the same code**, yet slightly modified, **compiled by g++ gives the expected result**.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char data[9];
    float a = 3.141592654;
    sprintf(data, "%x", *(unsigned int*)&a);
    printf(data);
    return 0;
}
```

Why do the results differ? Maybe there is a better way to do that?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could it be that the `sizeof(unsigned int)==2` is smaller than `sizeof(float)==4`? Could be if it is a 16bit uC.

Comment: What are `sizeof(float)`, `sizeof(float *)`, and `sizeof(unsigned int)` for both platforms?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie                                                                   
For g++ 32bit  float, float*, unsigned int, unsigned int* all == 4
For g++ 64bit  float == 4, float* == 4, unsigned int == 8, unsigned int* == 8
For Arduino  float == 4, float*== 2, unsigned int = 2, unsigned int* == 2

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure you want to see the bit pattern of a 4 byte variable, you should prefer a  conversion like this:

```
 sprintf(data, "%08lx", *(uint32_t*)&a);
```

(Here it's irrelevant, but in general, leading zeros help readability)

[edited to include @timemage's hint]

Comment: Their original problem seems to have arisen because they have a 16-bit `unsigned int` type. You've got `uint32_t` involved, which *sort of* solves one part. But, you have plain `x` specified for the format, which will be expecting 16-bits. You *could* cast the entire current value parameter to `unsigned long` and switch the specifier to `%lx`, or better (IMO) use `"%08" PRIx32` and `<inttypes.h>`/`<cinttypes>` to correctly match the `uint32_t` argument. I say *sort of* because technically this runs up against strict aliasing. Oversimplified: you'd need to `memcpy` `data` into `uint32_t`.

Comment: @timemage: The l in "%08lx" is definitely a point I missed for 8bit-Arduinos with 16bit int. Thanks for the PRIx32 hint.